# Create a bootable image from the contents of a .tar file

Tags: bootable, disk-image

Is there any way in Linux/Unix to create an Ext3 filesystem image from the contents of a `.tar` file?

The `.tar` file contains a rootfs folder structure, which I would like to make bootable with `grub` on Intel's Galileo development board.

Comment: A tar file is a compressed file...

Comment: You can't quite convert a .zip file to NTFS either...

Comment: I think he wants `dd` as in `tar -jxv /path/to/rootfs.tar | dd of=/dev/sdX conv=sync,noerror bs=xxxK`  where `bs=xxxK` is the number you used to tar the root fs.

Comment: @val0x00ff `-j` probably not, since there doesn't seem to be mention of bzip2 compression anywhere, and `tar -x ball.tar | dd of\/dev/sdX`? Unless the tarball contains a single file which actually is the image, than it's **very likely not** what is desired.

Comment: @peterph true! The `-j` option is wrong. That should be substituted to `-f`

Comment: @val0x00ff in that case it should come right before the file name, otherwise `xv` gets interpreted as tarball name and the actual `/path/...` as the file to be extracted from `xv`. Actually it will probably just complain that you didn't specify an action (add, delete, create and the like) to perform. :)

Comment: Strange this got closed as "needs details or clarity". Seems very clear what's being asked for and indeed has an accepted answer with 11 votes at time of writing.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Well ... yes and no. I still don't see from the question what the OP considers to be an `ext3` file (in particular considering that `.ext3` is taken as filename extension), and no requests for clarification were answered. The acceptance of the answer strongly indicates that an image file was meant, but the question was closed prior to that ... and still not updated afterwards and I do think the Q should include it. Maybe I will just "edit and reopen".

Comment: @AdminBee Yeah I would. And tbh there aren't really any other practical interpretations. I rather feel it was closed for pedantry rather than being genuinely unclear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Iff](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iff) by an .ext3 file you understand a filesystem image, then the process can be as follows:

- create the image file, e.g. with `dd`:

  ```
  $ dd if=/dev/zero of=image.ext3 bs=1M count=256
  ```

  this creates a 256MB file filled with zeros.
- create a filesystem on in that file:

  ```
  $ mkfs.ext3 image.ext3
  ```
- loop-mount the filesystem somewhere, extract the tarball there, unmount:

  ```
  $ mkdir /arbitrary/mountpoint
  $ mount -o loop image.ext3 /arbitrary/mountpoint
  $ tar -xvf image.tar -C /arbitrary/mountpoint
  $ umount /arbitrary/mountpoint
  $ rmdir /arbitrary/mountpoint
  ```

If you are trying to put it into a partition on e.g. an SD card, then replace `image.ext3` with the appropriate device file (e.g. `/dev/mmcbpl0p1` or `/dev/sdXY`) - and you will arrive at the standard way to create a filesystem.